# C# Manipulating JSON with generic object

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON that *mostly* looks like the following:

```
{
   "odata.metadata":"XXX",
   "value":[
      {
         "PartitionKey":"0000000001-0000000001",
         "RowKey":"8a6f7335-4cc7-4aaa-9b48-f719a1f56844",
         "Timestamp":"2016-11-07T18:19:59.3147580Z",
         "DistributionNumber":1,
         "Name":"General"
      },
      {
         "PartitionKey":"0000000001-0000000001",
         "Id":"bce10165-3a3e-4166-9907-2ed02c0f83fb",
         "Timestamp":"2016-11-07T18:20:17.1260274Z",
         "DistributionNumber":1,
         "Designation":"Secondary"
      }
  ]
}
```

I say "mostly" because the JSON can vary except for the following:

- There will always be a `odata.metadata` node off the root.
- There will always be a `value` node off the root which will be an array.
- The `value` array can have a varied number of items, each with a variety of name-value pairs **except** one will always be `PartitionKey`.

What I need to do is read the JSON into memory and strip out all the value items which do not have a `PartitionKey` = "0000000001-0000000001".

I have the following code so far:

```
var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
var value = (ArrayList)jsonObj["value"];
foreach (var item in value)
{
    if (item["PartitionKey"] != "0000000001-0000000001")
    {
        value.Remove(item.Key);
    }
}
```

Casting the `value` as an ArrayList seems to be the only way I'm able to access its data, but then I have trouble accessing the `PartitionKey` property.

How can I do what I want - test each item in value and conditionally remove them - in a generic fashion since the data in each `value` item can be different?

Comment: @itsme86 Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use a `Dictionary<string, string>` for the value properties. For example:

```
public class DataObject
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
    public string ODataMetadata { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now using JSON.Net:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataObject>(json);
```

And then filter out the values you don't want:

```
data.Value = data.Value
    .Where(v => v.Any(kvp => 
        kvp.Key == "PartitionKey" && kvp.Value == "0000000001-0000000001"));
```

Comment: Using `DeserializeObject` is what I would typically do, but, for some reason, I didn't think that would work unless I serialized all the properties.  Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed it looks like it converts `int` properties to `string`s meaning now key-value pairs where the value was not wrapped in quotes, now is.  Anything I can do about this given that the property names differ?

Comment: You could use `Dictionary<string, object>` instead (you will also need to do `kvp.Value.ToString()` in the comparison)

Comment: Would that resolve the issue I just described or not?

Comment: Not really sure what the issue is that you have, but it means the items will be decoded as `int` or `DateTime` instead of just `string`

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with JSON.NET's [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) feature:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);

var matchesPartitionKey = parsed["value"]
    .Where(x => x["PartitionKey"].ToString() == "0000000001-0000000001")
    .ToArray();
```

This will return an array of all items in the `value` array that have a matching `PartitionKey = 0000000001-0000000001`. You can then get the details of those items using the same syntax:

```
Console.WriteLine(matchesPartitionKey.First()["Name"]);
// "General"
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/L3EB53